# "Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found" when trying to install Memcache in Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, memcached, xampp

On Ubuntu, I am getting an error in memcache.

> Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found

I have xampp and I have installed memcached and memcach. Actually I want memcache and I don't know what is the problem. When I run through terminal, I get this:

```
/etc/init.d/memcached status
 * memcached is running
```

Also

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I'm using Ubuntu desktop version 32bit. Not getting where is the problem. Please be specific.

Answer (score 4):

You are only talking about the memcache-daemon, but to access it from PHP you also need the PHP-extension

```
sudo apt-get install php5-memcached
```

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/php5-memcached
- http://php.net/memcached

Don't forget to restart the server.

Comment: i have installed this but still getting same <br> error Class 'Memcache' not found

Comment: There are two PHP extensions providing support for memory cache. The one mentioned in this answer is implemented as `Memcached` class, not `Memcache`.

Comment: OK, now you should decide, which one of both you want to use: `Memchached` (as mentioned in the question) and `Memchache` (mentiond in your comment) are two different extensions: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/php5-memcache http://php.net/memcache

Comment: actually i was using windows there i was working on memcache but now working on ubuntu here i want memcache

Comment: @mace: OK, once again: On the one side there is the memcache-daemon (afair they are named "service" under windows). On the other side there are libraries, that access this daemon. For PHP you have _two_ different extension. Just install _one_ and use it ...

Comment: i think i have installed both :( that is y it is not working...should i uninstall memcached?? why u say?

Comment: You should _not_ remove `memcached`, but one of `php5-memcache`, or `php5-memcached`. `memached` is the daemon and it is completely independent from PHP or _any_ other language.

Comment: now i have installed php5-memcache and restarted xampp... but having same error, enable to find problem

Comment: thanks for replying ... but having this issue dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have extension = memcached.so in your php.ini.
Add this text as '`extension = memcached.so`' at the end of file.

And Restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu I had to do:

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-memcache
```

Note that there is no 'd' in the end